# Criar tabela no MySQL usando Laravel

Tags: android, mysql, banco-de-dados, laravel

Preciso criar uma tabela com o Laravel usando o comando migrate, a tabela no momento só teria o id. Normalmente seriam criadas 2 tabelas, uma com o nome do banco de dados que eu coloquei contendo os atributos, e outra tabela que faria o gerenciamento de dados, registraria sempre que a tabela fosse modificada. Só que toda vez que eu crio, aparece esses erros no Prompt:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E isso leva a 2 problemas. O primeiro é que as 2 tabelas são criadas, mas o nome de uma delas tá errado (deveria ser o nome que eu coloquei do banco de dados):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o segundo é que todas estão vazias, e não sei da onde surgiu esses campos da tabela users (que está com o nome errado):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como ainda estou aprendendo a usar, não sei o que acontece

Answer (score 1):

Uma alteração do Laravel a partir da versão 5.4 fazem com que o mysql 5.6 ou versões anteriores apresentem esse erro. Para corrigir basta ir no arquivo `AppServiceProvider.php` e no método `boot()` você adiciona `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` lembrando de importar a classe `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema`. Ficará mais ou menos assim:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

fonte: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser que a opção "innodb" do MySQL esteja desativada. Para verificar se ela está ativa entre no direito do mysql\bin\ abra o arquivo my.ini, procure pela linha "skip-innodb" veja se está comentada. Descomente a linha tirando o # do inicio, salve o arquivo e reinicie o MySQL. Depois disso exclua a table, crie novamente e rode o migrate.

Obs: Falo isso levando em conta que o código dentro da migration de users está correto, pois não vc não colocou ai, mas, mesmo assim segue abaixo um exemplo de como pode ser o código dentro de uma migrate de users:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal já resolvi o problema. Eu tinha escrito errado o nome do banco de dados mas o principal é que quando criei o migrate veio três arquivos PHP contanto com o da tabela, o users e o password, resolvi apagar esses dois e funcionou. Estranho mas ok.

Comment: Essas são migrates padrões do laravel que ele utiliza se você quiser o scaffolding de autenticação. Ele voltou a funcionar pq o erro era na criação da tabela de users que tem um campo de email que é unique. Minha resposta mais a baixo explica melhor o erro.